# RubyWarrior beginner epic solution

Tags: beginner, ruby, adventure-game

This is my RubyWarrior solution. I think [RubyWarrior](https://github.com/ryanb/ruby-warrior) is well known to Ruby coders.  I am starting to learn Ruby and I would appreciate some help from you to improve the organization or the mistakes that I could have. I don't need another example as the Internet is full of them, but what I need is some advice that I can use as a beginner.

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :health, :direction, :n, :view, :warrior
  def initialize
    @health, @direction, @warrior  = health , direction , warrior
    @direction  = [:forward , :backward]
    @health, @view = [] , [] 
  end

  def play_turn(warrior)
    @health << warrior.health
    @view = warrior.look
    @backview = warrior.look :backward
    senses = warrior.feel @direction[@n]
      if ( senses.wall? && next_empty?(warrior) ) || senses.wall? 
        warrior.pivot!      
      elsif @backview[1].to_s.include?("Captive")
        warrior.walk! :backward        
      elsif @backview[0].to_s.include?("Captive")
        warrior.rescue! :backward      
      elsif next_empty?(warrior) && senses.stairs? || safe_step?
        warrior.walk!
        puts "Hero :D Finally I made it!"
      elsif senses.captive?
        warrior.rescue! 
        puts "Hero ;)   feel free to face your destiny"
      elsif seek_and_shoot?
        warrior.shoot!
        puts "Hero >< BAAANNG!! Die already ranged scumbag"
      elsif warrior.health < 15 && safe?(warrior)
        warrior.rest!
        puts "Hero :(   I need to heal my wounds"
      elsif next_empty?(warrior)
        warrior.walk! 
        puts "Hero :|   go go go!"
      else
        warrior.attack!
        puts "Hero :x   I will kill you evil #{warrior.feel.to_s.upcase}!"
      end

    life_bar_on_screen
    puts @view
    puts @backview
  end 

  def loosing_life? warrior
    @health[-1] < @health[-2] ? true : false
  end

  def next_empty? warrior
    warrior.feel.empty?
  end

  def safe? warrior
    next_empty?(warrior) && !loosing_life?(warrior)
  end

  def life_bar_on_screen 
    puts "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ LIFE #{@health.last}"
    (1..@health.last).each { |x| print "▒ "} 
    puts ""
  end

  def seek_and_shoot?
    foe = [ "Wizard" , "Archer", "Sludge"] 
    o, oo, ooo = @view[0].to_s , @view[1].to_s , @view[2].to_s
    case 
      when o == "nothing" && foe.include?(oo) then true 
      #when o == "nothing" && ranged_foe.include?(oo) then true 
      #when o == "nothing" && oo == friend then false
      when o == "nothing" && oo == "nothing" && foe.include?(ooo) then true
      else false
    end
  end

  def safe_step?
    friend = "Captive"
    o, oo, ooo = @view[0].to_s , @view[1].to_s , @view[2].to_s
    case 
      when o == "nothing" && oo == friend then true 
      when o == "nothing" && oo == "nothing" && ooo == friend then true
      else false
    end
  end

end
```

### Shell output

> ```
> CONGRATULATIONS! You have climbed to the top of the tower and rescued the fair maiden Ruby.
> Level Score: 74
> Time Bonus: 6
> Clear Bonus: 16
> Level Grade: A
> Total Score: 503 + 96 = 599
> Your average grade for this tower is: A
>
>   Level 1: S
>   Level 2: A
>   Level 3: S
>   Level 4: A
>   Level 5: A
>   Level 6: A
>   Level 7: A
>   Level 8: S
>   Level 9: A
> ```

Comment: Congratz for your implementation and welcome to Ruby! The first thing that I looked into were those `ifs` inside `play_turn(warrior)` method. It would be more readable if you extract all those ifs to a Strategy or Chain of Responsibility class whom receives `warrior` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   def loosing_life? warrior
>     @health[-1] < @health[-2] ? true : false
>   end
>
>   def next_empty? warrior
>     warrior.feel.empty?
>   end
>
>   def safe? warrior
>     next_empty?(warrior) && !loosing_life?(warrior)
>   end
> ```

Why I see no reason not to just make these part of the `warrior` class. It would make calling these much cleaner as you're never passing anything *but* a `warrior` into them.

> ```
>   def life_bar_on_screen 
>     puts "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ LIFE #{@health.last}"
>     (1..@health.last).each { |x| print "▒ "} 
>     puts ""
>   end
> ```

The life bar is a really cool idea. I like that a lot.

> ```
>   elsif @backview[1].to_s.include?("Captive")
>     warrior.walk! :backward        
>   elsif @backview[0].to_s.include?("Captive")
> ```

Anytime the same string literal shows up more than once, I recommend using a constant instead. It will protect you from spelling errors that can cause runtime problems. Apply the same advice to your `seek_and_shoot?` method.

> ```
>   def seek_and_shoot?
>     foe = [ "Wizard" , "Archer", "Sludge"] 
>     o, oo, ooo = @view[0].to_s , @view[1].to_s , @view[2].to_s
>     case 
>       when o == "nothing" && foe.include?(oo) then true 
>       #when o == "nothing" && ranged_foe.include?(oo) then true 
>       #when o == "nothing" && oo == friend then false
>       when o == "nothing" && oo == "nothing" && foe.include?(ooo) then true
>       else false
>     end
>   end
> ```

The variable names here are pretty obtuse. What exactly are `o`, `oo`, and `ooo`? They're related somehow, but that's all I can readily gather from the names.

Also, commented out code is dead code. Remove dead code. If you're worried that you'll need it, then I recommend you start using source control of some kind. Personally, I like Git.